# How to remove from background the sample "AndroidMobilePushApp" project from SNS docs?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, background, multitasking, amazon-sns

I've started to learn how to integrate `AWS SNS` with my Android project using [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html#registration-id-gcm) AWS guide from the docs.

I have downloaded the `snsmobilepush.zip` file from the website, on step 3, and added the code as a new project. I followed the steps written in the guide, but since I installed it on my device, I cannot close it. It has to remain in background, and if I'm closing it then it opens up after 2-3 seconds.

Is there any way that I could close it from background and still get push messages?

Answer (score 0):

This sample has been around for a number of years, it could be that it's not automatically adding the icon to the notification drawer and requires the app to be running.

I would suggest using Mobile Hub, which is the preferred way for Mobile Developers on AWS to get started. Once you enable push notifications (or any other features you want), you can download a sample app that shows more up to date usage. (https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home#/)